# Why express line and graph_objects scatter plot different dates on the same data?

Tags: python, date, plotly, line, scatter

The identical dataset of funding dates vs disciplines plotted differently using plotly.express (px) lines and plotly.graph_objects (go) scatter traces. The shape of the plots look identical, but dates are wrong in the go traces. Any suggestions on what may be wrong here? Thank you.

Using px.line:

```
fig = px.line(df_fig, x='date_list', y='monthly_avg', color='main_discipline')
```

[image]

Using go.Figure

```
plot = go.Figure()
  
plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name = 'Data 1',
    x = df_fig.date_list,
    y = df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==1].monthly_avg,
    stackgroup='one'
   ))
plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name = 'Data 2',
    x = df_fig.date_list,
    y = df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==2].monthly_avg,
    stackgroup='one'
   ))
plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name = 'Data 3',
    x = df_fig.date_list,
    y = df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==3].monthly_avg,
    stackgroup='one'
   ))
plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name = 'Data 5',
    x = df_fig.date_list,
    y = df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==5].monthly_avg,
    stackgroup='one'
   ))
```

[image]

The date_list is of type datetime64:

```
df_fig.date_list

0      1975-06-01
1      1975-06-01
2      1975-06-01
3      1975-06-01
4      1975-07-01
          ...    
2455   2026-07-01
2456   2026-08-01
2457   2026-08-01
2458   2026-08-01
2459   2026-08-01
Name: date_list, Length: 2460, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Removing stackgroup produced plots of the same shape, but the wrong ending date persists at Mar 1988 instead of Jul 2026.

[image]

Here is the data frame with the first 20 rows, the date issuse persist

```
df_fig[['date_list', 'main_discipline', 'monthly_avg']]
```

```
date_list   main_discipline monthly_avg
0   1975-06-01  1   0.000000
1   1975-06-01  2   15494.000000
2   1975-06-01  3   0.000000
3   1975-06-01  5   0.000000
4   1975-07-01  1   0.000000
5   1975-07-01  2   16827.333333
6   1975-07-01  3   0.000000
7   1975-07-01  5   0.000000
8   1975-08-01  1   3880.252381
9   1975-08-01  2   16827.333333
10  1975-08-01  3   0.000000
11  1975-08-01  5   0.000000
12  1975-09-01  1   3880.252381
13  1975-09-01  2   16827.333333
14  1975-09-01  3   0.000000
15  1975-09-01  5   0.000000
16  1975-10-01  1   201134.985609
17  1975-10-01  2   986805.179029
18  1975-10-01  3   590159.728836
19  1975-10-01  5   0.000000
```

Using px.line

```
fig = px.line(df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==1], x='date_list', y='monthly_avg')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Using go.Scatter

```
plot = go.Figure()
plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name = 'Data 1',
    x = df_fig.date_list,
    y = df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==1].monthly_avg,
))
plot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you don't use a filled area plot and remove the argument `stackgroup='one'` from your traces? This could help you directly compare the plots a bit better

Comment: @DerekO I removed stackgroup='one', the shapes of the plots are more or less identical, but the wrong ending dates are still at 1988 instead of 2026.

Comment: This is peculiar. I notice there are 4 repeated dates in the `df_fig`. What does it look like when you go down the second? Does this problem persist if you plot, say half of your df_fig? What if you only plot the first 100 points? If the same issue persists with a much smaller subset of your df, then you can paste it into the question and we can directly help you debug whatever is causing this

Comment: The 4 repeated dates correspond to the 4 main_disciplines. I extracted the head 20 rows (added in the description). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you are unintentionally passing different data to `go.Scatter` and `px.line`. In the below code snippet, you are passing `x=df_fig.date_list` which is all of the date_list values, but only some of the monthly_avg (subset by main_discipline==1).

```
plot = go.Figure()
plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name = 'Data 1',
    x = df_fig.date_list,
    y = df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==1].monthly_avg,
))
plot.show()
```

Plotly should probably throw `ValueError: all arguments should have the same length` for this situation, but instead tries to plot it anyway by shortening the array you passed to x to match the array you passed to y. `df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==1].monthly_avg` has a length of 5, and the first 5 values of `df_fig.date_list` are the following:

```
>>> df_fig.date_list
0    1975-06-01
1    1975-06-01
2    1975-06-01
3    1975-06-01
4    1975-07-01
```

This explains the plot you were getting, but this is definitely not what you want and instead this should give you the correct result:

```
plot = go.Figure()
plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    name = 'Data 1',
    x = df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==1].date_list,
    y = df_fig[df_fig.main_discipline==1].monthly_avg,
))
plot.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Derek! You saved my sleep tonight :-)

Comment: @Peng no problem! I know how frustrating it can be when there isn't an error but the result doesn't make sense... this definitely feels like a situation where if Plotly had thrown `ValueError: all arguments should have the same length`, it would have been a lot easier to figure out what was happening :P

Answer (score 0):

- you have just shared a list of dates, have created a dataframe that has all required columns
- refactor use of **go** to be less repetitive
- fundamentally you are requesting different formatting by setting `stackgroup`
- **px** will use *scattergl* for very large plots, this doesn't support `stackgroup`. Hence updating traces does not work to make **px** plot similar to **go** plot for large date range

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd

ed = "1-aug-2026"
ed = "1-aug-1976"
df_fig = pd.DataFrame({"date_list": pd.date_range("1-jun-1975", ed)}).assign(
    main_discipline=lambda d: ((d.index % 5) + 1).astype(str),
    monthly_avg=lambda d: np.geomspace(1, 5 * 10 ** 7, len(d)) * d["main_discipline"].astype(int),
)

fig = px.line(df_fig, x='date_list', y='monthly_avg', color='main_discipline')
fig.show()
try:
    fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(stackgroup="one"))
except ValueError:
    print(f"{fig.data[0].type} doesn't support stackgroup")
    
fig.show()

plot = go.Figure()
for k, d in df_fig.groupby("main_discipline"):
    plot.add_trace(go.Scatter(name="Data "+k, x=d["date_list"], y=d["monthly_avg"], stackgroup="one"))

plot.show()
plot.update_traces(stackgroup=None).show()
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I see the difference in scattergl vs scatter. But the main issue I have here is the date_list is shortened by go plot from July 2026 to Mar 1988. The data is identical, the shape of the plots are the same, very puzzled ...